# How can I read 1 value from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to use

```
(list).pop(i)
```

I want to know if there is a better command.

In more detail:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.pop(0) #This should equal 1
```

Unfortunately, pop removes the number from the sequence, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

I am a beginner, so please give simple/detailed answers.

Comment: `lst[0]`...?! Please give us some more details about what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it is already a built-it function.

Comment: What meaning about you "read"? If you just wanted to print, `list[i]`. It need not use pop().

Comment: Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: So, you *are* asking for `a[0]`...

Comment: It seems you should start reading the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read a specific item in index i:**

```
item = L[index]
```

**Read a sequence of items from index 'start' to index 'stop':**

```
seq = L[start:stop]
```

**Iterate over a list:**

```
for item in L:
    print item
```

**If you need both the index and the item, use the enumerate function:**

```
for index, item in enumerate(L):
    print index, item
```

**You can also get the reversed list:**

```
L.reverse()
```

**Get list length:**

```
length = len(L)
```

And there are so much more operations you can perform on lists.

Comment: Really good stuff man :)

Comment: Python is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `list[i]` , `i` being the index of the element to be read.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to print a list:

```
for i in a:
  print(i)
```

`a` being the list.

---

To print a list element:

```
print(a[index])
```

`index` being the position within the list(`0` to `len-1`)

---

If you just want to check if a value exists in the list:

```
value in a
```

`value` being the value searched and `a` being the list.

Comment: Print the list as many times as there are elements in the list...?! :-P

Comment: @deceze no. The typo is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list three ways:

**1. If you want just each element in the list:**

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

**2. if you want the index of the elements in a list:**

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i)
```

**3. If you want the index and the corresponding elements in the list:**

```
for i, e in enumerate(a):
    print(i, e)
```

These are the three main methods of looping over lists.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the i-th element in `aList` with `aList[i-1]`. Positions range from 0 to list length minus one.

You can treat the list as a stack. See Python [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) for details. Stacks are equipped with method `pop()` for extracting an element from the *top*.